# WPF async httpclient not returning string

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, rss, httpclient

```
public RSS_Reader()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

public static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string pageURL)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.parliament.uk/g/RSS/news-feed/?pageInstanceId=209&limit=20");
    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;

}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter as string;
    strURL = parameter.ToString();

    Task<string> strXML = DownloadPageAsync(strURL);

    ListBoxRss.Items.Add(strXML.Result);
 }
```

Part of a wp8 app I've been making. There's the main landing page of the app which links to the second page from where I took the code above. Second page never actually loads and it just hangs on the first page.

What have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `OnNavigatedTo` method async and await the `DownloadPageAsync` method:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter as string;
    strURL = parameter.ToString();

    string strXML = await DownloadPageAsync(strURL);

    ListBoxRss.Items.Add(strXML);
}
```

Comment: Yay oh yay, I get to finish reading parliamentary highlights!